# How can I refactor the code with many unions

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a package where I need either to do same (or similar) unions many times or not at all depending on parameters. The code below is simplified. But the real one would be a bit more complex. As I wish to avoid dynamic statements I though I create a temp view and do operations on this view.

```
PROCEDURE CREATE_VIEW( id IN BINARY_INTEGER, id2 IN BINARY_INTEGER, id3 IN BINARY_INTEGER) IS
sqlCommand VARCHAR2(32000);

BEGIN
    sqlCommand :=
    'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TMP_HELPER_VIEW AS 
    SELECT ID, IMPORT1_ID, IMPORT2_ID, PROD_ID
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT ID,
               IMPORT1_ID,
               -1 AS IMPORT2_ID,
               PROD_ID                
          FROM TABLE1
          WHERE IMPORT1> '|| id1;

       
    IF id := 123 THEN    
        sqlCommand := sqlCommand||
        'UNION
        SELECT ID,
               -1 AS IMPORT1_ID,
               IMPORT2_ID,
               PROD_ID               
          FROM TABLE2
          WHERE IMPORT2> '|| id2;
    END IF;
    sqlCommand := sqlCommand||')' ;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  sqlCommand;                
        

END CREATE_VIEW;
```

With view I can do:

```
SELECT ID, IMPORT1_ID, IMPORT2_ID FROM TMP_HELPER_VIEW;
```

Instead of

```
 sqlCommand := 
          'SELECT ID,
           IMPORT1_ID,
           -1 AS IMPORT2_ID,
           PROD_ID                
      FROM TABLE1
      WHERE IMPORT1> '|| id1;
       
    IF id := 123 THEN    
        sqlCommand := sqlCommand||
        'UNION
        SELECT ID,
               -1 AS IMPORT1_ID,
               IMPORT2_ID,
               PROD_ID               
          FROM TABLE2
          WHERE IMPORT2> '|| id2;
    END IF;
```

So the code would be much better readable as I have many functions which uses similar statements. Statements are always bit different, so I need to write them every time (I can't write one in function and call evey time from there).
But I wonder if there is a better solution for this problem. Maybe someone can give me any clue.
Many thanks!

Comment: what is the purpose of the procedure. Is it just to create views? Or do you plan to return a cursor or some other value from this proc?

Comment: Only to replace the view. Depending on id parameter I need to view which makes a union or not. I can operate on tables but my goal is to avoid a lot of if-clauses and dynamic statemments.

Comment: well if the union is dependent on a proc parm, than dynamic sql my be your best bet without fully digging into what you are trying to do.  I can't really understand the requirements of why you would want to replace a view over and over again but I guess this might be the best way.

Comment: You still have dynamic statement, but now they are dynamic DDL statements, which is probably worse. I would probably solve this scenario with a [table function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm). You can just open the individual queries and pipe them as a result, instead of unioning them in a dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having a dynamic statement anyway, but in addition, you're storing that in a view. The use case is not very clear to me. If this is some sort of one time configuration to set up the view for a customer/installation, I think this could be fine.

If however, you're using this to generate different queries on the fly, I think it's risky. Two clients can be fighting to each generate their own version of the view, leading to unwanted, unpredictable results. The first client can create their version of the view, but by the time they want to use it, another client may have replaced it.

So for that, there are various better solutions, for example

1. Have the 'big' union of all tables in the view. Filter out unneeded rows from the results. This looks inefficient, but can be surprisingly fast, especially if you're using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`. The latter filters out duplicate rows, and it looks like your won't need that.
2. Create a [`pipelined table function`](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_IBYPQ5XC76JGAXOZTH6KK0QM1.html). Open the needed queries one by one, and pipe their results to the output. You can use the function as a sort of parameterized view.
3. Create a function that generates the desired query, but instead of storing it as a view, return a cursor (`sys_refcursor`) based on the query. The caller can read the results of that cursor. Other clients can make consecutive calls and get their own cursor, without interfering with each other.
4. A mix between the two above would be to write a function that generates the query, bulk collects the results a table type and returns it. Very simple to implement, but may be less memory efficient, so less suitable for larger result sets.
5. If you're on one of the recent innovation versions, you can use [SQL Macros](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/tutorial_KQNYERE8ZF07EZMRR6KJ0RNIR.html) to generate the SQL snippet you need.

It's hard to tell which one of this is best in your specific situation, but I've used each of these successfully in our application.

Example for 4.

```
create type IMPORT_R as object (
  ID int,
  IMPORT1_ID int,
  IMPORT2_ID int,
  PROD_ID int
);
create type IMPORT_T as table of IMPORT_R;

CREATE FUNCTION GetImport(
  id IN BINARY_INTEGER, 
  id2 IN BINARY_INTEGER, 
  id3 IN BINARY_INTEGER) 
return IMPORT_T
IS
  sqlCommand VARCHAR2(32000);
  v_Result IMPORT_T;
begin
    sqlCommand :=
        'SELECT ID, IMPORT1_ID, IMPORT2_ID, PROD_ID
        FROM 
        (
            SELECT ID,
                   IMPORT1_ID,
                   -1 AS IMPORT2_ID,
                   PROD_ID                
              FROM TABLE1
              WHERE IMPORT1> '|| id1;

       
    IF id := 123 THEN    
        sqlCommand := sqlCommand||
        'UNION
        SELECT ID,
               -1 AS IMPORT1_ID,
               IMPORT2_ID,
               PROD_ID               
          FROM TABLE2
          WHERE IMPORT2> '|| id2;
    END IF;
    
    sqlCommand := sqlCommand||')' ;
    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sqlCommand BULK COLLECT INTO v_Result;
    
    return v_Result;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you. I definately need something memory efficient as the result sets are very huge. Maybe I will try to add some extra information to the view and use the first solution but without replacing it all the time. What is the best solution for large result sets?

Comment: The code appears to be "Example for 4." and not "Example for 5."

Comment: I think 2, 3 and 5 should work as well as the view. 2 possibly even better, although it depends on so many details, its hard to say. How much data is this about?

Comment: The table1 has around 14 000 000 entries. The table 2 has around 1,5 million. I take around 1000 - 2000 (based on some conditions with evtl. more unions) and need only to count (distinct) them. I don't need to proceed them in other way.

Comment: Although it can't hurt to dive into the other solutions, the specified solution 4 should work okay if you got result sets of a few thousand rows.